# Is a contraceptive diaphragm considered to be a chatzizah for mikvah immersion?

Tags: women, mikvah-ritual-bath

In comparison with many intrauterine contraceptives, the diaphragm is "readily removable" by the female user between uses. Would an inserted diaphragm be considered a chatzizah for mikvah immersion? If not, would some be machmir to remove it in any case, despite no water reaching that area? If yes, then why?

Comment: The common practice is to be strict to remove absolutely everything where feasible. Do you have some reason to think this would be different? (It's fine to ask about the Bedieved case; I just don't understand why you think to ask about the Lechatchila case.)

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, being inside the woman (although removable and temporary), it doesn't come in to contact with the mikvah water at all. So why would there even be a need lechumra?

Comment: How is that different from [Lechatchila] teeth flossing?

Comment: @DoubleAA I have seen it written that the mouth is open slightly during immersion. Hence water enters the mouth. Many (from certain sects) come in to the dental practice to ask for temporary fillings to be removed so that they can immerse in a mikvah. A diaphragm is different

Comment: That's not true. No water enters the mouth during immersion. (and: gross!) The lips just shouldn't be pressed too tightly together as to unnecessarily wrinkle any skin around the mouth. Shulchan Arukh YD 198:38 אינה צריכה לפתוח פיה כדי שיכנסו בה המים, ולא תקפוץ אותה יותר מדאי, ואם קפצה, לא עלתה לה טבילה, אלא תשיק שפתותיה זו לזו דיבוק בינוני: The issue of temporary fillings is just are they more similar to a permanent false tooth (not a chatzitza) or to a popcorn stuck in your teeth (chatzitza).

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks. Maybe write an answer to this effect. Although I would appreciate a consideration that water can enter the mouth but cannot enter the other place.

Comment: I don't have material here for an answer. Maybe someone does somehow distinguish diaphragms from popcorn. The question just seems off by not acknowledging the obvious reason one might remove something that isn't sticttly speaking a chatzitza: we always remove anything when feasible [to avoid questions or whatever]

Comment: This question has been addressed as long as such contraceptives were available. See [Pische Teshuva 198:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Pithei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.198.16?lang=bi). (Obviously contemporary poskim deal with additional specifics and broader scope (e.g. R. Ovadiah Yosef, Taharat HaBayit vol. 3), this is simply pointing to the “classics” addressing the question.

Comment: http://www.yoatzot.org/questions-and-answers/answer.asp?id=727, http://www.yoatzot.org/questions-and-answers/answer.asp?id=3396, and dozens more